# Can I subscribe to types of questions?

Tags: support

Can I subscribe to questions and is there a way to filter those subscriptions (for example, by tag or a search filter or something)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subscribe to tags, hover over any [tag](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) you want to subscribe to and you will see details about the tag and options for `rss` and `subscribe` - thats how I subscribed to the daily Joomla Questions on SO.

e.g.

[image: Tag popup for Joomla on StackOverflow]

Answer (score 5):

You can subscribe to tagged searches. I get daily emails from Stack Exchange on questions matching "joomla".

To set it up, go to https://stackexchange.com/filters and log in. From there, you can set up a filter that emails you a daily summary of questions and links to them for answering. Pretty useful.